# Form Reset causes "out of stack space" error with jquery.validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, internet-explorer-10

I have a form that (in it's simplest form) is like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>PC Trade Up - Test </title>
</head>
<body id="tech">
    <div id="page">
        <section id="main">
            <h2>
            Test
            </h2>
            <form action="/tech/migration/test" method="post">
                <input id="test1" name="test1" type="text" value="" />    
                <div>
                    <button type="Submit" id="formSubmit" class="btn">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                    <button type="Reset" id="formReset" class="btn">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="/content/js/lib/jquery.form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can use this form and submit with no issues. When I hit the Reset button however I receive "SCRIPT28: Out of stack space" in the IE10 console.  Oddly perhaps, I cannot reproduce this in Firefox.

I've avoided the issue by removing the jquery.form.js reference, but this is included in my bundle.  The error seems to bubble out of jquery.validation.js.  I've traced this to line 417 of this script which reads as follows:

```
resetForm: function () {
    if ($.fn.resetForm) {
        $(this.currentForm).resetForm();
    }
    this.submitted = {};
    this.lastElement = null;
    this.prepareForm();
    this.hideErrors();
    this.elements().removeClass(this.settings.errorClass).removeData("previousValue");
},
```

The line

```
$(this.currentForm).resetForm();
```

seems to call recursively for 254 iterations before producing this error, (makes sense).  But I cannot determine the source of the recursion.  I understand that triggering an event on a descendant will bubble and cause this kind of loop, but I do not see where I am doing this, nor do I see this in this script.

Any suggestions for determining the source of the recursion or loop?

Comment: $(this.currentForm).resetForm(); is calling resetForm and you are getting a stackoverflow!

Comment: Fals,  Thanks for the response.  Please let me clarify.  Firstly, the function above is not my own.  It is from the jquery.validate.js library which works fine on it's own (no stack overflow).  The problem appears when the jquery.form.js library is referenced.  This too is not my own.  It seems (and I'm guessing here) that each is handling the reset event and triggering the other, leading the the stack overflow.

My question is whether there is a setting (or an update) that can prevent this.  Has anyone else encountered this with these two libraries?

Comment: I'm currently investigating the same issue. I'm running with a pretty minimal test case now and I think there's a conflict between jquery.validate.unobtrusive and jquery.form both adding handlers to the form reset event. I'll keep you updated. It's not specific to IE 10, I've reproduced this in 8, 10 and 11. 9 is probably also affected.

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ULrP/) to reproduce the bug. It loads jQuery and jQuery Validation, while including only the necessary parts of jQuery Form Plugin and Unobtrusive Validation. At this point I'll probably make some bug reports.

Comment: https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/398

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I am able to solve it by commenting out the aforesaid function:

```
    resetForm: function() {
        if ( $.fn.resetForm ) {
            //$(this.currentForm).resetForm();
        }
        this.submitted = {};
        this.lastElement = null;
        this.prepareForm();
        this.hideErrors();
        this.elements().removeClass( this.settings.errorClass ).removeData( "previousValue" );
    },
```

I know there should be some proper implementation but this patch solves problem as of now, I tried in FF & Chrome too and it seems to be working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to change any of the existing jquery.forms code, so I implemented this is a separate javaScript file that is loaded after jquery.form. This script should only be loaded for IE.

```
(function($) {    
    $.fn.resetForm = resetForm;
    function resetForm() {
        return this.each(function() {
            // guard against an input with the name of 'reset'
            // note that IE reports the reset function as an 'object'
            if (typeof this.reset == 'function' || (typeof this.reset == 'object' && !this.reset.nodeType)) {
                $.fn.resetForm = undefined;
                this.reset();
                $.fn.resetForm = resetForm;
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nice one Ray. Us folks in Manchester appreciate it!